# Tailwindcss Unable to remove gap in image please guide

Tags: tailwind-css

Screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3c94.jpg

Hello Developers please help me to remove that spaces in the right side image gap in the top
side of image how to reduce it, i searched alot and tested few method but not pass
please guide. I am new to this Tailwindcss. Thanks for the support.
See Image Screenshot

Please check screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3c94.jpg

````
<body>
 <!-- Navigation Menu -->

 <nav class="relative contain bg-slate-900 mx-auto p-4">
<!-- Flex Container -->
<div class="flex items-center justify-between">
<!-- Logo -->
<div class="pt-2 mx-auto">
    <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="FIVERACK">
</div>
<!-- Menu Items -->
<div class="hidden space-x-5 text-yellow-200 mx-auto md:flex">
    <a class="font-normal hover:font-bold" href="#">Pricing</a>
    <a class="font-normal hover:font-medium" href="#">Products</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Careers</a>
    <a href="#">Community</a>
</div>
<!-- Button Right Side  -->
<a href="#" class="hidden p-2 px-6 text-white bg-brightRed rounded-full baseline md:block">Get Started</a>
</div>
 </nav>
<!-- Hero Section -->
<section id="hero">
<!-- Flex Container -->
<div class="container flex flex-col-reverse md:flex-row items-center px-6 mx-auto mt-10 space-y-0 md:space-y-0">
    <!-- Left Item -->
    <div class="flex flex-col mb-32 space-y-12 md:w-1/2">
    <h1 class=""></h1>
    <h1 class="max-w-md text-4xl font-bold text-center md:text-5xl md:text-left">
        Bring Everyone Together To Build Better Products
    </h1>
    <p class="max-w-sm text-enter text-darkGrayishBlue md:text-left">
        Manage makes it simple for software teams to plan day-to-day tasks while keeping the 
        larger team goals in view.
    </p>
    <div class="flex justify-center md:justify-start">
        <a href="#" class="p-2 px-6 text-white bg-brightRed rounded-full baseline">Get Started</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Image -->
    <div class="md:w-1/2">
        <img src="img/tech_stack.png">
    </div>
</div>

</section>
</body>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIgkL.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLYP2.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `items-center` to `items-start` in `Flex container` div

Change this :

```
<!-- Flex Container -->
    <div class="container mx-auto mt-10 flex flex-col-reverse items-center space-y-0 bg-blue-400 px-6 md:flex-row md:space-y-0">
```

to

```
 <!-- Flex Container -->
    <div class="container mx-auto mt-10 flex flex-col-reverse items-start space-y-0 bg-blue-400 px-6 md:flex-row md:space-y-0">
```